# Objective-Cでグローバル定数を定義したファイルをPrefix.pchでインポートする方法

Tags: objective-c, xcode

http://qiita.com/ytka/items/512468814bf15d937f2b
このページを参考にして、グローバルな定数を定義するファイルを作成しました。

MyConstant.h

```
#undef _EXTERN
#undef _INITIALIZE_AS

#ifdef _DEFINE_GROBAL_CONSTS_
 #define _EXTERN
 #define _INITIALIZE_AS(x) =x
#else
 #define _EXTERN extern
 #define _INITIALIZE_AS(x)
#endif

_EXTERN NSString* const kAddMessageNotification _INITIALIZE_AS(@"addMessage");
```

MyConstant.m

```
#define _DEFINE_GROBAL_CONSTS_ 1
#import "RRGConstant.h"
```

このファイルで定義した定数は多くのファイルで使用するため、
Prefix.pchでインポートしました。

```
#import "MyConstant.h"
```

すると、MyConstant.mで

```
#define _DEFINE_GROBAL_CONSTS_ 1
```

より前にMyConstant.hがインポートされてしまうためか、定数が定義されず、エラーが出ました。
（Prefix.pchでインポートせず、定数を使用するそれぞれのファイルでインポートした場合には、うまくいきました。）

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_kAddMessageNotification", referenced from: ...
```

この定数ファイルは多くのファイルから利用するので、できればPrefix.pchでインポートしたいのですが、どのようにすれば良いでしょう。

Comment: 今更ですが、`GROBAL`でなく`GLOBAL`では？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyConstant.mの`Compiler Flags`に`-D _DEFINE_GROBAL_CONSTS_=1`を設定してください。

[image: スクリーンショット]